# What exactly are formalizations in logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Studying logic there is one thing which I never quite grasped and hope one of you can help.

The problem regards formalization of natural language to any logical language and whether the translation scheme/glossary “fixes” the meaning of the propositional variables (or whatever variables/constants the translation requires) like an interpretation, or whether we merely abstract away from the non-logical elements by replacing them with variables ranging over the relevant objects (having them be non-interpreted). Because if we just render the argument in question in a tidier language, then how do we achieve the desired abstraction which we want with formalization - as far as I know we formalize to bring out the logical form by  abstacting away the non-logical parts of natural language sentences (and if we maintain the meanings of the non-logical parts in the translation, then we do not have an abstract form, a schema - we have the same sentence just written symbolically).

Say I want to formalize the following argument:

If it rains, then the streets are wet. It rains. Therefor the streets are wet.

Using the following translation key/“glossary”:

P: It rains
Q: The streets are wet

We get:

P —> Q, P |= Q

Having used the key, does the above propositional logic argument now read (or have the meaning of): “If it rains —> the streets are wet”, “It rains”, |= “The streets are wet”?

Or is the key just to make sure that we do not use two different sentences for the same propositional variables and that the argument is just a “logical form” so to speak?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So, here is part of your question.

> The problem regards formalization of natural language to any logical language and whether the translation scheme/glossary “fixes” the meaning of the propositional variables (or whatever variables/constants the translation requires) like an interpretation, or whether we merely abstract away from the non-logical elements by replacing them with variables ranging over the relevant objects (having them be non-interpreted).

It presents us with two alternatives:

- The meaning of propositional variables are fixed in a given context by their interpretation.
- Propositional variables don't have a meaning. They are instead surrogates for meaning-bearing elements that we use to stay entirely within the land of mathematical formalism.

These perspectives are in a certain sense both valid.

The first perspective is valid when we have a model. A model is an interpretation, but an entirely mathematical one described using set theory alone, with no reference to the real world.

There is a notion of *truth in a model*. For example $M \models P \to Q$ is false, where $M$ is a model in which $P$ is true and $Q$ is not true. We might also write this as $\{ P \} \not\models P \to Q$ ... and say that a model is a set of primitive propositions that are true.

The second perspective is valid when we're thinking *syntactically*.

There's a purely syntactic notion of proof, and when we're working with proofs syntactically we don't need to consider models at all.

The second perspective is also valid in a certain sense when we're thinking about a semantic notion of entailment.

$ \Gamma \models \Delta $ if and only if (for all models $M$ such that $M \models \Gamma$, it holds that $M \models \Delta$), where $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ are sets of well-formed formulas.

---

What you're doing in your example with a key/glossary is a bit different.

Classical logic is sometimes described as *giving a correct account of inference*. This isn't really true; there are alternative logics that accept different inferences than classical logic does like [intuitionistic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic) and the many [relevance logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_logic) and it's entirely possible that none of them are a good account of correct inference (if that's even a coherent idea).

However, it is certainly possible to *use classical logic as if it gave a complete account of inference*. The way to do this is to translate propositions into sentences and logical connectives into grammatical conjunctions of various kinds.

In this case, what you're doing is taking a classically valid inference rule, modus ponens $P \to Q, P \models Q $, and you're translating it into natural language in a given interpretation.

1. If it's raining, then the streets are wet.
2. It's raining.
3. Therefore, the streets are wet.

This certainly seems to be valid.

It's important to note what you've done here, though. You can use this to prove that the *concrete argument is valid* given that *modus ponens is valid*.

However, you can't use this to prove that *modus ponens is valid* given that the *concrete argument is valid*. In order to prove the validity of modus ponens, you need to prove it in every interpretation, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

Formalisation of a natural language statement does not "fix" the meaning of words, but rather the opposite: it replaces potentially suggestive phraseology like "it is raining", by neutral terminology, like a propositional variable. Formalising a natural language argument requires you to make clear what assumptions you are making about the terms like "it rains" and "the streets are wet" involved.

In your example of an informal argument, someone could argue, "everyone knows that if it rains, then the streets are wet, so that assumption is not needed". The formalisation makes it clear that assumption is an essential part of the logic of the argument.

Answer (score -1):

Abstraction is the process of eliminating detail rather than eliminating the non-logical parts. This is because the natural language example you've given is still logical as written. So rather than eliminating it we're merely tokenizing it with a symbol so suppress some information but still acknowledging it's existence as a logical statement in that context. Engineers will occasionally say something like "assume you have a spherical chicken in a vacuum" to poke fun at the fact we often, in practice, abstract away detail in an illogical way.

Comment: What is illogical about approximating a chicken as a sphere? Or a mass concentrated at a point?

Comment: This joke is used by Leonhard in the big bang theory, but it is not a good joke. Even in something so simple as the free fall, we need assumptions to be able to calculate relevant data, here for example the time the fall takes. This is nothing illogical. It is necessary because reality is too complex to be exactly quantitative describable.

Comment: @RobArthan Chickens are not actually spherical nor do they exist in a vacuum.

Comment: @Peter the joke predates that show by several decades. I've not actually seen it but I'm told it's only funny for stupid people. You don't have to convince me that assumptions are useful but I'm not convinced they're logical. They're simplifications so our tiny brains can make sense of the world. The sciences are essentially a pragmatic hallucination.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Well, I cannot prevent you from having this opinion, but I disagree , at least in the case of the classical physics. The modern physics with its relativity theories and the cosmology is another story.